# Prevent text from wrapping under a checkbox

Tags: html, css, layout, checkbox

I'm laying out a set of checkboxes and I am running across the age-old issue of text wrapping underneath a checkbox if the text is too long.

My HTML:

```
<div class="right">
    <form id="updateProfile">
        <fieldset class="checkboxes">
            <p>4. What is your favorite type of vacation?</p>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Ski Trips"> Ski Trips</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Beach Visits"> Beach Visits</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Cruises"> Cruises</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Historical and educational trips"> Historical and educational trips</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Yachting"> Yachting</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Road Trip"> Road Trip</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Spa Weekend"> Spa Weekend</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Bed and Breakfast"> Bed and Breakfast</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Stay home and relax"> Stay home and relax</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Gambling Trips"> Gambling Trips</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Volunteer"> Volunteer</label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
div.right{width:580px;}

form#updateProfile fieldset label{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/7WmGr/

After much searching on different sites, I can't seem to find a reasonable solution. I am open for suggestions on changing my markup/styles, but I would like to keep the code as clean and semantic as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: [Basically same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23472949/923560), with IMHO best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203459/923560

Comment: @Abdull well yeah, this question was asked 7 years ago so...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/7WmGr/5/

I gave the `label` a `margin-left` of 18px and the checkboxes a `margin-left` of -18px.

Seems to work in Chrome & IE9.

```css
div.right {
  width: 598px;
}

form#updateProfile fieldset label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

form#updateProfile fieldset label input[type='checkbox'] {
  margin-left: -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <form id="updateProfile">
    <fieldset class="checkboxes">
      <p>4. What is your favorite type of vacation?</p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Ski Trips"> Ski Trips</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Beach Visits"> Beach Visits</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Cruises"> Cruises</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Historical and educational trips"> Historical and educational trips</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Yachting"> Yachting</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Road Trip"> Road Trip</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Spa Weekend"> Spa Weekend</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Bed and Breakfast"> Bed and Breakfast</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Stay home and relax"> Stay home and relax</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Gambling Trips"> Gambling Trips</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Volunteer"> Volunteer</label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to make it Margin-right instead of left for the 18px; this then stops the text from overlapping

Comment: Bad practise to nest checkbox inside label according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Accessibility_concerns

Comment: `elements such as anchors or buttons`. If you see the "Do", you'll notice the anchor tag is moved outside of the label. The checkbox is still within the label and is completely valid.

Answer (score 14):

I like this ...

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Ski Trips"><label>very long label ...</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] { 
    position: absolute;
}
input[type="checkbox"] ~ label { 
    padding-left:1.4em;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**The simplest option**

HTML:

```
<form id="updateProfile">
    <fieldset class="checkboxes">
        <p>4. What is your favorite type of vacation?</p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Ski Trips"> Ski Trips</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Beach Visits"> Beach Visits</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Cruises"> Cruises</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Historical and educational trips"> Historical and educational trips</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Yachting"> Yachting</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Road Trip"> Road Trip</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Spa Weekend"> Spa Weekend</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Bed and Breakfast"> Bed and Breakfast</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Stay home and relax"> Stay home and relax</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Gambling Trips"> Gambling Trips</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Volunteer"> Volunteer</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display:flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: This is great, though I found align-items: center worked a little better in aligning the checkbox with the text.

Comment: Nice answer. In my case, I like it better with `align-items: flex-start`

Comment: Thanks, worked out well

Answer (score 5):

One option would be something like this.

```
form#updateProfile fieldset label{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    position: relative;
}

input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/opoqon/1/edit

The way I tend to do it is different, which is not wrapping `inputs` with `labels`, rather doing something like

```
<input id="ski-trips" type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Ski Trips"><label for="ski-trips">Ski Trips</label>
```

which then allows for easier styling.

Here is an example of that way: http://jsbin.com/otezut/1/edit

But either way would work.

Comment: You are my hero! I've tried countless ways of doing this and this worked the best and most reliably for me! Thank you!

Comment: Am I missing something? The second method looks absolutely horrendous - checkboxes on one line, labels on another, the one long label totally breaking the flow of the rest of them; basically, everything that can go wrong with a list of checkboxes, the second jsbin demonstrates.

Comment: @Martha Considering this is over two years old, it should definitely be scrutinized. Looking at it now, I'd likely opt for a different approach.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that's less reliant on the size of the input elements.

```css
div {width: 12em;}

label {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

label input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<label><input type="radio"><span>I won't wrap</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><span>I won't wrap</span></label>

<label><input type="radio"><span>I am a long label which will wrap</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><span>I am a long label, I will wrap beside the input</span></label>

</div>
```

Comment: Most concise answer that has a label wrapping the input and span. Cool use of whitespace wrap to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tried all the options and the best solution for was:

```html
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox"><span>Text</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"><span>Text</span></label>
</div>
```

HTML like Pudica and Fillip suggested.

And the CSS you only set the `float:left` to the `checkboxes` and to prevent the text wrap around the checkbox you can simply use `overflow:hidden` on the `span`.

```css
[type="checkbox] {
   float: left;
}
span {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can use `margin-left` to give desired space from text to checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use a table for layout in this case.  Rather than fiddling with a thousand different possible permutations of css because supposedly tables are evil, this just works 100% of the time.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type=checkbox id=blah><label ='blah'></label></td>
    <td><label for='blah'>Long label here...</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And if you need a label next to your checkbox for styling purposes then just use an empty label tag there and use the real label in the second table cell.  (Yes, you can use multiple labels for the same checkbox)

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary extra code.

Comment: @Dgloria If extra code makes it reliable and readable, then that's code well spent.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option. It's very simple yet effective. 
You take the part that's wrapping. `<label><input type="checkbox" name="vacation" value="Historical and educational trips"> Historical and educational <span class="antiWrap">trips</span></label>` and you add a span with a class. I called the class antiWrap. Then you use css to add a left margin to it like. `.antiWrap { margin-left: 18px; }` Here's myfiddle based using your code. http://jsfiddle.net/alexhram/7WmGr/3/ I think that's what your going for? Let me know.

Comment: @mookamafoob nesting `input`in a `label`doesn't change the layout because `label`doesn't render anything on the screen. However you should only put the the options text in this case "historical and educational trips" inside the `label` according to the example on w3schools.com. That's enough to add that effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to see if there is a way to apply a style that applies to all cases, without adding additional markup.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrapped the checkbox and the label in a div and added display:flex. That has left alignment by default.

```
<div class="checkFlex">
   <input
   type="checkbox"
   class="form-check-input"
   name="..."
   id="..."
   v-model="..."
   @change="..."
   />
   <label for="...">This is a label</label>
</div>
```

```
.checkFlex{
  display:flex;
}
```