# how to keep radio button label from going below the input when wrapping

Tags: asp.net, css, label, word-wrap, radiobuttonlist

I have a long list of radio buttons generated by ASP.NET. ASP.NET renders the input and label inside a table cell, and makes the label and input siblings, using label for=xxx.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxLqxobc/2/).  The labels are quite long, many of them.

When the labels wrap, the goal is to have them look like this:

```
( )  cdsdcsdcsdc akd adckldsjcj dlsck acsd dscj dlkc dcas
     df sdf dfkl dksf dfs dlkf
```

rather than like this;

```
( ) cdsdcsdcsdc akd adckldsjcj dlsck acsd dscj dlkc dcas
df sdf dfkl dksf dfs dlkf
```

or like this:

```
( )
 cdsdcsdcsdc akd adckldsjcj dlsck acsd dscj dlkc dcas
df sdf dfkl dksf dfs dlkf
```

Assuming that the markup cannot be changed, what would the CSS be to achieve that styling?

P.S. Per the answer cited by rogerdeuce:

```
   input[type=radio]
        {
            float: left;
        }
        label
        {
            display: block;               
            margin-left: 2em;
        }


        #sites td:after {
         content: "";
         clear: both;
     }
```

Comment: like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472949/prevent-wrapping-of-text-below-radio-buttons

Comment: thanks! That does work. The trick was clearing after the td.

Comment: Also a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty simple to achieve your desired output.

Change the `input` and `label` to:

```
display: inline;
```

`inline-block` adds whitespace above and below the element, `inline` does not.

Hope this helps.